# Automatically select a textfield upon loading new VC

Tags: ios, swift

Im sure this is simple but I can't figure it out so I thought I'd ask! I have a tab view controller with 5 different tabs on it. On one of them, when somebody clicks on it, I want the cursor to be automatically selected in the textfield so they can start typing right away. How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select a text field with

```
textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

You'd probably want to put that in you `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```